# LINQ, joining results of two methods

Tags: linq

I want to create a flat result set from the results of two methods in which the results of the first are the arguments for the second.

For example, method 1 returns `1,2,3` and I want to feed each int into method 2, which just returns `4,5,6` every time.

So I expect back a resultset like `1:4, 1:5, 1:6, 2:4, 2:5, 2:6, 3:4, 3:5, 3:6`

If possible, I want to do this in a single LINQ query (pref c#).
I hope this explanation is clear and someone can help me.

EDIT:

I shouldn't have asked. This is easy. For anyone else who needs it:

```
int[] aList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var enumerable = from a in aList
                 from b in GetResult(a)
                 select new { x = a, y = b };
```

Comment: Instead of answering your question in your question, you should post your own answer and accept it in two days, or accept someone else's answer already posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ expressions

```
void Main()
{
    var method1 = new[] {1,2,3};
    var method2 = new[] {4,5,6};

    var res = from m in method1
        from m2 in method2
        select String.Format("{0}:{1}", m, m2);

    foreach (var x in res) {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(x);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for SelectMany.

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>> method2 = () => new [] {4,5,6};
(new [] {1,2,3})
    .SelectMany(m1Arg => method2().Select(m2arg => string.Format("{0}:{1}",m1Arg,m2arg)));
```

In query syntax, it's two *from*s as in

```
var q = from a in List
        from b in List2
        select a,b...
```

Comment: Wow, generally I prefer the explicit syntax, but this appears to be one case where the query syntax is much cleaner and clearer.

Comment: Agreed, for Join and the join case of SelectMany, query syntax is simpler